# Sherlockaction Bar NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS Changes on orentation?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

When changing from a vertical view to a horizontal view, the NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS will automatic changes to a list? May i know how do i fix this to NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to fix, as this is by design. The native action bar does this as well. I filed [an issue pointing out this behavior](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24439), and was told that the action bar is working as intended. ActionBarSherlock, in turn, aims to mirror Android's native behavior.

If you want tabs that are *always* tabs, use anything other than action bar tabs, such as:

- `ViewPager` with a tab indicator (`PagerTabStrip`, `TabPagerIndicator` from the ViewPagerIndicator library, etc.)
- `FragmentTabHost`
- Etc.